# I can't write in file, despite my print working

Tags: python

The message I want to write into the file is printed perfectly fine, like this:

> What do you want the name to be? sample1.txt
>
> {97/A2/H-+9H6/7+8H63@/.H89>H6981H+19TH98/H90H>29=/HA29H2+=H+H6+8-/H+8.H+8-3/8>H=23/6.H98H+H=2/60H+8.H5//:=H+H=5388CH8+1H+8.H+H1
>
> This is the encrypted message.

However, when I check the file, there is no contents. The code is as follows:

```
file = file_contents()
total = key_offset()
encrypted = ''
character_number = 0
length = len(file)

while character_number < length:
    char = file[character_number]

    ordinal = ord(char)
    encrypted_ordinal = ordinal + total

    if encrypted_ordinal > 126:
        encrypted_ordinal = encrypted_ordinal - 94

    encrypted_char = chr(encrypted_ordinal)
    encrypted = encrypted + encrypted_char
    character_number += 1

    if character_number == length:              
        encrypt_file = input("What do you want the name to be? ")
        file1 = open(encrypt_file, "w")
        file1.write(str(encrypted))
        print(encrypted)
        print("This is the encrypted message.")
        the_menu()
```

As I try to decrypt, the obvious error is that there are no file contents. If I need to provide anything, please comment.

Comment: When are you closing `encrypt_file`?

Comment: Do I need to close it? Is it that simple of a mistake...?

Comment: Maybe. Especially if you reuse the still open `encrypt_file` for reading.

Comment: Thanks, that was it, I cant believe that, I had multiple students check it...

Comment: If a comment answered your question, either get the author of that comment to write it as an answer - and accept it, or write your own answer (and accept it). Editing the title to say the question is answered is different to accepting an answer.

Answer (score -1):

I usually use with for reading and writting to files.

```
with open('encrypt_file.txt', "wb") as file1:
    file1.write(str(encrypted))
```

it closes the file automatically although it is considered bad python code (but not bad Cpython code)